# Routing in an ASP.NET Core app with Angular

Tags: .net, angular

I have created a project using the template in visual studio as below -

[image]

This has created the 'WeatherForecast' controller with a simple get method. I would like to add additional methods to this controller as a test but when accessing this methods, the Angular homepage is returned. As a test I have navigated to the urls in a browser and correctly see the json returned for /get but the Angular homepage is returned for /MyTeam. I imagine there is a simple configuration I've missed somewhere but after hours of searching I'm stuck.

[image]

**JSON returned correctly for get method**

[image]

**I'm expecting to see the same JSON returned here**

[image]

**Question - how can I expose additional methods in the controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both the methods have the same default route

```
[Route("")]
```

Try changing the route for the other get methods. You can either decorate the method using:

```
[HttpGet("team")]
```

or

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("myteam)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was going to be something simple!